# Localhost bloqueado en XAMPP en Windows

Tags: php, web, windows, xampp

quiero empezar un proyecto en php pero a la hora de iniciar XAMPP y meterme en localhost, me salta este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado varias opciones pero ninguna me funciona, e incluso he cambiado los puertos predefinidos por otros puertos, pero tampoco funciona. Además tengo desactivada la opción de "Internet Information Services" ¿Alguien sabe como se puede solucionar? Gracias

Comment: fijate las extensiones de chrome que tengas activas, ahi dice que tiene problemas con las extensiones... prueba con otro navegador para descartar esto ultimo tambien, puedes probar con firefox,safari,opera ... etc

Comment: Has creado la regla del firewall para conexiones de entrada?

Comment: @David081 Con respecto a las extensiones, ya lo tengo solucionado, una extensión hacia conflicto, pero ahora me salta este otro error: "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: @SrPanda no, ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Esta [guia](https://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/) explica bien como añadir una